# How can I set up a CSS style for min and max width for responsive website?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my code. Because I am trying to create a responsive website using min and max width using the media queries. Some parts of my queries are fine but there is an element that doesn't read my CSS media query.

I have a navigation sidebar in the left side. And I want to resize it using media queries. But if I resized it. It doesn't read the min-width I include in the media query. When I check the code. only the color property is working. When I debug it using developer tools in Chrome. It read the CSS from the other CSS file named 'product.css' and not my 'responsive.css'.

What should I do?

Here's my simple CSS for responsive.css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1603px) {

    #searchhandler { 
        color: red; 
        min-width: 310px;
    }

}
```

Here's the CSS from my product.css

```
#searchhandler {
    width: 20%;
    display:none;
    min-width: 316px;
}
```

I am really a newbie in CSS that's why I am having a hard time with this part.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved my problem. It is not the media query but the links for inluding the CSS file in my header.

My old code is like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/product.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/responsive.css" />
```

It should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/responsive.css" media="all" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/product.css" />
```